# How to get array with values into one column

Tags: arrays, excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

In excel I have two columns (A and B) filled with text values and I want to get all the values from the two column into one column (C) and it needs to be dynamic

example:

```
Column A: {car, plane, boat}
Column B: {bike, motor}
Column C: {car, plane, boat, bike, motor}
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Excel is not Google Sheets. Which of the two are you actually using?

Comment: And if excel. Which version?

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(A:C); "where Col1 is not null")
```

Comment: does it work for excel?

Comment: @milan1610 ofc not. this is for google sheets as you tagged your question

Answer (score 2):

Google Sheets has a FLATTEN function which allows you to do this, but there is no equivalent function in Excel.

There is a [workaround](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/oo29mp/flatten_equivalent_in_excel/) though, which does combines the 2 columns in the order of their rows:

This works in Excel Version 2019 or later

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",TRUE,A:B)&"</b></a>","//b")
```

Comment: One note on this method: TEXTJOIN has a limit of 255 characters.  If the number of characters including the reuse of `</b><b>` is greater than 255, it will error.

Comment: does it work for excel?

Comment: @milan1610 it will for any version greater than 2019 and office 365 Excel.

Comment: Nice approach for combining the 2 columns.

Answer (score 2):

This will work in both Excel(any version) and Google Sheets:  Put this in C1 and copy down till you have enough cells filled to capture both lists maximum lengths:

```
=INDEX(A:B,IF(ROW($ZZ1)>COUNTA(A:A),ROW($ZZ1)-COUNTA(A:A),ROW($ZZ1)),IF(ROW($ZZ1)>COUNTA(A:A),2,1))&""
```

[image]

With Office 365 Excel:

```
=LET(
    rng1st,A:A,
    rng2nd,B:B,
    cnt1st,COUNTA(rng1st),
    cnt2nd,COUNTA(rng2nd),
    sq,SEQUENCE(cnt1st+cnt2nd),
    INDEX(CHOOSE({1,2},rng1st,rng2nd),IF(sq>cnt1st,sq-cnt1st,sq),IF(sq>cnt1st,2,1)))
```

Put that in C1 and the results will spill automatically:

[image]

Comment: It works fine but it gives an error (#REF) in column C on the cells were is a blank cell in one of the two columns (A and B). So If column A has values till row 60 and B has filled rows till 100 It show #REF from line 61 in column C

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(range1)+ROWS(range2))<ROWS(range1)+1,range1,INDEX(range2,MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(range1)+ROWS(range2),,ROWS(range2)-ROWS(range1)),ROWS(range2))+1,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(range2))))`
This will stack range2 under range1 in Excel (365) this also works for ranges with 2 columns, or more

Answer (score -1):

**If the amount of the rows won't be changed**

=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$3, ROWS(C1:$C$1)), IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$2, ROWS(C1:$C$1)-ROWS($A$1:$A$3)), ""))

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

**If the amount of the rows can be changed**

=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("$A$1:$A$"&COUNTIF(A:A,"*")), ROWS(C1:$C$1)), IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("$B$1:$B$"&COUNTIF(B:B,"*")), ROWS(C1:$C$1)-ROWS(INDIRECT("$A$1:$A$"&COUNTIF(A:A,"*")))), ""))

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>